# Flutter error in GridView.count : Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..4: 5

Tags: flutter, gridview

This is my first question here.
(So if anything went wrong please let me know.)

I am pretty new to Flutter and was trying to apply `GridView.count` in my app but the following error occurred.

```
Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..4: 5
```

I saw `ListView` has a similar problem and from the solution, I tried to find something like `itemCount` or `childCount` but didn't find anything like that.

So my code is as bellow. The main `GridView.count` is called like this:

```
body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2, 
        children: buttons,
      )
```

and the widget list, `buttons` is set by `getButtonList()` function:

```
List<Widget> buttons = [];

void getButtonList() async { 
List<Map> list = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM test WHERE mom > 2');
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  //print(list[i]['name']);                 //this seems ok
  setState(() {
    buttons.add(RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(list[i]['name']),
      ),
    );
  });
}



// and later in Floating Action Button callback like this

floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      getButtonList();
    },
  ),
```

I also tried returning a temporary list from `getButtonList()` and wrap with `setState` in the floating action button like this:

```
List<Widget> buttons = [];

Future<List<Widget>> getButtonList() async {
List<Widget> temp = [];
List<Map> list = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM test WHERE mom > 2');
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  //print(list[i]['name']);     
  setState(() {
    temp.add(
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text(list[i]['name']),
      ),
    );
  });
}
return temp;
}



// and Floating Action Button callback like this

floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    List<Widget> temp = await getButtonList();
      setState(() {
        buttons = temp;
      });
    },
  ),
```

still, the same error message is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work. What I did was declared a `temp` list and updated that list. Later in setState `temp` is passed to the original `buttons`.

I think there should be a better way.

Anyway, my present working code is as follow:

```
List<Widget> buttons = [];
List<Widget> temp = [];

void getButtonList() async {
List<Map> list = 
                await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM test WHERE mom > 2');
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  print(list[i]['name']);
  buttons.add(
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text(list[i]['name']),
    ),
  );
}


// and Floating Action Button callback like this

floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      getButtonList();
      setState(() {
        buttons = temp;
      });
    },
  ),
```